# AOT error after upgrading to Angular v4 final

Tags: angular, angular2-aot

After updating form the last v4-rc to v4 final, I get following error message when calling "ng build -prod" and have no idea where to start looking for the problem.

> > >
> >     ERROR in c://src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts (1,1): Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
> >     <<<

The message is repeated once more, but no additional information is given.

Any ideas?

Kind regards,
Marc

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5620  https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5623

Answer (score 2):

From Angular-cli team:

> We fixed a problem with AOT and templates where errors were not always
>   reported. Now they should be. This may surface previously hidden bugs
>   that existed in your codebase.

So this is an intended behavior.

What the error says is that you are calling a method but the arguments you provide do not match the declaration of this method.

Example

Method declaration:

```
private myMethod(arg: any) {}
```

How you call it:

```
this.myMethod();
```

---

In my own case, I was using the router transition callback:

```
@Component({
  ...,
  host: { '[@routerTransition]': '', '(@routerTransition.done)': 'init($event)' },
  ...
})
```

And the declaration of the init method was as followed:

```
public init() { }
```

I had to fix it by adding the missing argument:

```
public init(event: any) { }
```

---

NB: It could probably be the other way around: calling a function with more arguments than required.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Already heard about them having changed a bit and also had to change some code, even some of these kind of errors. But this one error message keeps me tapping in the dark. No hint to where to look for. And tsc also does not find any problems, so I guess it is somewhere in a template and I will have to investigate each and every template :(

Comment: @Ploppy Can you inform us how did you find out where your bug was. When compiling with -aot we don't get any compiled code unless you get success with compilation. I have similar error somewhere in my template but I can't find which method it is!

Comment: You don't fixed the AOT compiled code. You fix the original .ts code. I recommend you to use the Visual Studio Code IDE along with this awesome extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template which warns you about many AOT compilation errors in your template files.